# An attempt at implementing Maybe in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, optional

I gave a shot at implementing `Maybe` for C++ and a slight twist in my implementation is that it uses `thread_local static` instance of `Just` and `Nothing` + placement `new` operator to minimize the number of (de)allocations.

This is the first time I'm using `thread_local` and placement `new` operator, so I could be doing something really wrong here. I would appreciate if you could take a look at the code and give your feedback.

**Maybe.hpp:**

```
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

namespace ro {
  /*
   * A class that may or may not hold a value in it.
   */
  template <typename T>
  class Maybe
  {
  public:
      /*
       * A deleter that doesn't actually delete the pointer. This is used to make sure that
       * the thread_local static instance on the stack doesn't get deleted when going out
       * of scope
       */
      struct NoopDeleter
      {
          void operator()(Maybe<T>*) {}
      };
      using pointer_t = std::shared_ptr<Maybe<T>>;

      /*
       * Gets an pointer to a Maybe that's nothing
       */
      static pointer_t nothing();

      /*
       * Gets a pointer to a Maybe that just have a value.
       */
      static pointer_t just(const T& value);

  public:
      Maybe() = default;
      virtual ~Maybe() = default;

      /*
       * Returns if this Maybe is nothing
       */
      virtual bool isNothing() const = 0;

      /*
       * Gets the value, if this instance has one. Throws a runtimer_error otherwise.
       */
      virtual T get() const = 0;

      /*
       * Gets the value held or the passed in value otherwise.
       */
      T getOrElse(const T& defaultValue) const
      {
          if (isNothing())
          {
              return defaultValue;
          }
          return get();
      }

      /*
       * Gets the value stored or throws the exception as supplied by the method passed in
       */
      T getOrThrow(const std::function<std::exception()>& exceptionSupplier) const
      {
          if (isNothing())
          {
              throw exceptionSupplier();
          }
          return get();
      }

      /*
       * Binds a function to convert the stored value (if any) to another of the same type
       */
      pointer_t bind(const std::function < T(const T&)>& func) const
      {
          return map<T>(func);
      }

      /*
       * Binds a function to convert the stored value (if any) to another Maybe of the same type
       */
      pointer_t flatBind(const std::function<pointer_t(const T&)>& func) const
      {
          return flatMap<T>(func);
      }

      /*
       * Maps the current value (if any) to another type.
       */
      template <typename U>
      typename Maybe<U>::pointer_t map(const std::function<U(const T&)>& func) const
      {
          return flatMap<U>([&](const T& val) { return Maybe<U>::just(func(val)); });
      }

      /*
       * Maps the current value (if any) to another type, using the method that returns a
       * Maybe of the mapped type.
       */
      template <typename U>
      typename Maybe<U>::pointer_t flatMap(const std::function<typename Maybe<U>::pointer_t(const T&)>& func) const
      {
          if (isNothing())
          {
              return Maybe<U>::nothing();
          }
          return func(get());
      }
  };

  template <typename T>
  class Nothing : public Maybe<T>
  {
  public:
      virtual bool isNothing() const override
      {
          return true;
      }

      virtual T get() const override
      {
          throw std::runtime_error("No value has been set for this.");
      }
  };

  template <typename T>
  class Just : public Maybe<T>
  {
  public:
      Just(const T& value)
          : mValue(value)
      {
      }

      virtual bool isNothing() const override
      {
          return false;
      }

      virtual T get() const override
      {
          return mValue;
      }

  private:
      const T mValue;
  };

  template <typename T>
  typename Maybe<T>::pointer_t Maybe<T>::nothing()
  {
      thread_local static Nothing<T> nothingInstance;
      static typename Maybe<T>::pointer_t nothing(&nothingInstance, NoopDeleter());
      return nothing;
  }

  template <typename T>
  typename Maybe<T>::pointer_t Maybe<T>::just(const T& value)
  {
      // Found out that thread_local isn't a good idea for 'just'.
      // thread_local static Just<T> justInstance(value);
      // typename Maybe<T>::pointer_t just(new (&justInstance) Just<T>(value), NoopDeleter());
      // return just;
      return std::make_shared<Just<T>>(value);
  }
}
```

Here's a working example: [ideone](http://ideone.com/RJlBUZ)

Comment: Fair point. Admittedly, I really didn't look into the help-center for rules, never have, but I guess I learned my lesson. I think this question isn't off-topic. What I'm specifically looking for is correctness of my code. While I think this might work, I'm not sure of any edge-cases where this may go horribly wrong.

Comment: Aside: There are reviews of a number of optional/maybe-types for C++ on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Allocation**

The thing that jumps out at me most is the need for memory allocation to create a `Just<T>` or `Nothing<T>`. That's a performance hit, which is why [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) and what will eventually be [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) don't do it this way.

It additionally makes the usage of the class a bit awkward. What I want to do:

```
Maybe<int> result = foo(x);
if (isNothing(result)) { ... } // or any other way to check
```

but I have to write:

```
Maybe<int>::pointer_t result = foo(x);
if (result->isNothing()) { ... }
```

That's awkward.

**`get()`**

You have `get()` returning *by value*, this incurs unnecessary copies at best, but if `T` isn't copyable makes `Just<T>` useless. You should instead prefer:

```
virtual T& get() = 0;
virtual T const& get() const = 0;
```

Returning `T` for `getOrElse()` makes sense though - as you may want to support the else case as a temporary. On the other hand, `getOrThrow()` will only ever return `get()` so it should return a reference.

**`std::function` is for type erasure**

Throughout, you use `std::function`. But `std::function` is for type erasure. It's for those cases where you need to store a functor. In none of your usages do you need this feature.

At the most basic, take `getOrThrow()`. Just take it as template argument:

```
template <typename F>
T& getOrThrow(F&& exceptionSupplier) {
    if (isNothing()) {
        throw std::forward<F>(exceptionSupplier)();
    }
    return get();
}

template <typename F>
T const& getOrThrow(F&& exceptionSupplier) const {
    return const_cast<Maybe*>(this)->getOrThrow(std::forward<F>(exceptionSupplier));
}
```

If you want to add more SFINAE goodness here, you could additionally require that `exceptionSupplier()` gives you something that inherits from `std::exception`.

But this is just an overhead thing. Your implementations of `map`, `flatMap`, `bind`, and `flatBind` all take as arguments a `std::function` of some sort too. This is ok but inefficient for `bind` and `flatBind`, but makes `map` and `flatMap` much less usable:

```
Maybe<int>::pointer_t result = ...;
auto add1 = result->flatMap([](int i){ return just(i+1); }); // error
```

because I have to write it like:

```
auto add1 = result->flatMap<int>([](int i){ return just(i+1); }); // OK but blargh!
```

Prefer something like:

```
template <typename F,
          typename R = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T&>()), // this is your Maybe<U>::pointer_t
          typename MaybeU = typename R::element_type // this is your Maybe<U>
          >
R flatMap(F&& func)
{
    return isNothing()
        ? MaybeU::nothing()
        : std::forward<F>(func)(get());
}
```

This would let users call your functions with raw lambdas - which is what they'd expect to be able to use!